# websracping with beautifulsoup

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, request

I'm trying to extract data from a website, [MKT CAP](https://www.hkex.com.hk/Market-Data/Securities-Prices/Equities/Equities-Quote?sym=82&sc_lang=en), but my code is not working. here is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://www.hkex.com.hk/Market-Data/Securities-Prices/Equities/Equities-Quote?sym=82&sc_lang=en'
page = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
results = soup.find(id='lhkexw-quoteequities')

job_elements = results.find_all("dt", class_="ico_data col_mktcap")
for job_element in job_elements:
    print(job_element.text)
```

I want - for example, to return **HKD730M**, but it's not returning any result.

I tried removing `.text` in the end but it just returned `<dt class="ico_data col_mktcap"></dt>` instead of the text.

Comment: `requests` package/library can only give you source page of the url. To find source page, hit `Ctrl+U` or `Cmd+U` in the browser.

Comment: yes, so on source page it is <dt class="ico_data col_mktcap"></dt> but when i run inspect it is supposed to be <dt class="ico_data col_mktcap">HK$730M</dt>, how do i get the right thing?

Comment: easy way is to selenium, little roundabout is inspect xhr, or inspect javascript. You can try looking solution on this [API Docs](https://www.hkex.com.hk/-/media/HKEX-Market/Services/Next-Generation-Post-Trade-Programme/Fini/FINI-API-User-Guide.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in comments, since the page is JS rendered you can get values using selenium webdriver or form url or api endpoints through xhr in Network tab.

Luckily, this one doesn't require any headers

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import time
import json

URL = 'https://www.hkex.com.hk/Market-Data/Securities-Prices/Equities/Equities-Quote?sym=82&sc_lang=en'
with requests.Session() as session:
    page = session.get(URL)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
    # results = soup.find(id='lhkexw-quoteequities')

    # use any of these, whichever works, to get script containing token
    script = soup.find('script', string=re.compile('getToken')).text
    # script = soup.select('#mainform > script')[-2].text

    token = re.findall(r'return "([\w%]*)"', script)[0]   # <script> ... return "evLtsLsBNAUVTPxtGqVeGzlj8lD5nf%2FIQqVHLVpcPY2jiminGmnwOZZ2%2FSc9wCFA"; ... </script>
    sym = re.findall(r'sym=(\d*)', URL)[0]
    qid = 2     # use time.time() * 1000 if this doesn't work
    callback = 'c=1'

    api_url = f'https://www1.hkex.com.hk/hkexwidget/data/getequityquote?sym={sym}&token={token}&lang=eng&qid={str(qid)}&callback={callback}'
    res = session.get(api_url).text
    json_data = json.loads(res[4:-1])["data"]["quote"] # c=1({"data": {"quote":json_data}})
    print(json_data)
    print("market cap:", json_data["mkt_cap"])   # market cap: 724.18
    print("value in:", json_data["mkt_cap_u"])   # value in: M
```